# Trouble Installing AudioKit/Core 4.11 for watchOS App with CocoaPods

Tags: audiokit

I am running Xcode 11.7. When I `pod install` in Terminal, I get an error saying -

```
[!] Unable to read the license file `LICENSE` for the spec `AudioKit (4.11)`
```

And also when I tried to import AudioKit into my project (just for giggles), I got a "Failed to load module `AudioKit`" error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. #AudioKit

Answer (score 0):

We are aware of these issues and are exploring our options to provide a fix. Hopefully we'll have functional frameworks for Xcode 12 in the coming days.